# Java Play Framework "java.util.NoSuchElementException: Call setControllerComponents..."

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am trying to inject a (Scala) controller from another (Java) controller, using `javax.inject.Inject`. The code looks something like this (simplified):

Scala Controller

```
class A @Inject()(config: Configuration) extends InjectedController with Logging {
  @Trace
  def getValues(): Action[AnyContent] = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Java Controller

```
public class B extends Controller {
    @Inject
    Configuration configuration;
    private A a;


    public AuditToolsController() {
        this.a = new A(configuration);
    }

    public run(){
        a.getValues();
    }
}
```

But I am getting a `java.util.NoSuchElementException: ControllerComponents not set! Call setControllerComponents or create the instance with dependency injection.` error. I can't seem to find out how to import and call `setControllerComponents`, it seems to be defined in the `InjectedController` trait in the `Controller.scala` class (which I can't extend in the Java class). How can I call this function to make this error go away?

I have also tried to inject the `A` controller directly, e.g. `@Inject A a` but that leads to a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, I'm not sure why..

My knowledge of Play, Java, and dependency injection is very rudimentary so apologies if the error is obvious, but I couldn't find any documentation or other stack overflow questions that address this issue.